# Networkxのリンクをグラデーションに染めたい

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib, networkx

#### 前提

3次元のグラフを作成しました。テキストファイルのトポロジー情報を読み込み3次元のグラフをmatplotlibによって出力するといったものです。

#### 実現したいこと

本プログラムのリンクをグラデーションを加えてみたいと考えています。

#### 該当のソースコード

本ソースコードは前提の項で述べた3次元のグラフを出力するものですが、`cmap='ocean'`を追加しています

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

path = fd.askopenfilename()

# 3.2_トポロジー情報(.txt)の読み込み
with open(path, "r") as tf:
    line = tf.read().split()
ran = int(len(line) / 2)

# 3.3_エッジのリストを読み込む
G = nx.read_edgelist(path,nodetype=int)
edge_size = nx.number_of_edges(G) # リンク数
node_size = nx.number_of_nodes(G) # ノード数

# spring_layout アルゴリズムで、3次元の座標を生成する
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, dim=3)
# 辞書型から配列型に変換
pos_ary = np.array([pos[n] for n in G])

# ここから可視化
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

# 各ノードの位置に点を打つ
ax.scatter(
    pos_ary[:, 0],
    pos_ary[:, 1],
    pos_ary[:, 2],
    s=200,
)

# ノードにラベルを表示する
for n in G.nodes:
    ax.text(*pos[n], n)

# エッジの表示
for e in G.edges:
    node0_pos = pos[e[0]]
    node1_pos = pos[e[1]]
    xx = [node0_pos[0], node1_pos[0]]
    yy = [node0_pos[1], node1_pos[1]]
    zz = [node0_pos[2], node1_pos[2]]
    ax.plot(xx, yy, zz, cmap='ocean')

# 出来上がった図を表示
plt.show()
```

以下は読み込むべきテキストファイル(トポロジー情報)です。

```
1 10
1 11
1 14
1 20
2 9
2 12
2 13
2 15
2 16
3 10
3 11
3 20
4 5
4 8
4 9
5 4
5 9
6 7
6 14
7 6
7 18
8 4
8 11
8 14
8 19
9 2
9 4
9 5
10 1
10 3
11 1
11 3
11 8
11 13
12 2
12 16
13 2
13 11
14 1
14 6
14 8
15 2
15 17
15 21
16 2
16 12
17 15
18 7
18 21
19 8
19 20
20 1
20 3
20 19
20 21
21 15
21 18
21 20
```

エラー文は以下の通りです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/Python36/質問用.py", line 47, in <module>
    ax.plot(xx, yy, zz, cmap='ocean')
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 1471, in plot
    lines = super().plot(xs, ys, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1743, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 273, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 419, in _plot_args
    for j in range(max(ncx, ncy))]
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 419, in <listcomp>
    for j in range(max(ncx, ncy))]
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 312, in _makeline
    seg = mlines.Line2D(x, y, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\lines.py", line 390, in __init__
    self.update(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 996, in update
    raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object "
AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no property 'cmap'
```

Comment: 目に付いた単語で、実際にはmatplotlibでは出来ない(実装されていない)ことをやろうとしているのでは？ 似たようなことをしているpython/matplotlibか、それに限らずExcel,GnuPlot,R,OpenGLといった何かで実現されている結果の例・図やソースコードがあるなら、それを紹介して自分では何をやろうとしているのか追記してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 例えばNetworkXでNodeやEdge毎に色を変える記事がこちらにあります。[【Python基礎】NetworkXでネットワーク図作成：NodeとEgdeの色をカラーマップで指定、透明化する方法](https://3pysci.com/networkx-3/) あとNetworkXは関係無いですが`グラデーション`という単語関連だとこんな記事が。[matplotlibで色をグラデーションにする](https://qiita.com/ShoheiKojima/items/6705ce31d6cffb64daff), [【python】matplotlibでグラフに色を指定する方法【カラーマップ】](https://note-tech.com/matplotlib-color/), [How to illustrate a 3D graph of gradient descent using python matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64940632/9014308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

実現したいことは「29個の辺の色を順番に少しずつ変えていく」と解釈して記述例を示します。
なお，実行環境は「 macOS13(M1), Python 3.10.8, matplotlib 3.6.2 」ですが，この matplotlib は `ax = Axes3D(fig)` では描画できなかったので変更しています。また，辺と色の対応がわかりやすいように凡例も付加しました。

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm  # added

# ...

# ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# ...

for i, e in enumerate(G.edges):
    node0_pos = pos[e[0]]
    node1_pos = pos[e[1]]
    xx = [node0_pos[0], node1_pos[0]]
    yy = [node0_pos[1], node1_pos[1]]
    zz = [node0_pos[2], node1_pos[2]]
    ax.plot(xx, yy, zz, linewidth=5,
            color=cm.ocean(i/(edge_size-1)),
            label=f'{e[0]:2d} - {e[1]:2d}')

hndls, lbls = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=hndls, labels=lbls,
          loc='center left',
          bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 0.5),
          fontsize=6)

plt.show()
```